# How to obtain a user's profile picture using only their @handler

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I have a Python bot for Telegram, and the idea, to summarize, is that given a user input containing mentions, I would like to obtain either the photo of the mentioned user or their user.id. I have a code that works for users without a handler, but I would like to find a way that works for all users.

```
entities = message.parse_entities()

if not entities:
    return

for entity in entities:
    if entity.type not in {"mention", "text_mention"}:
        continue

    user = entity.user

    if not user:
        print(">>> user not found") # this only happen for who have @username
        continue

    print(">>> user", user.id, user.name) # this works for non @username
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) can not resolve usernames to user ids. This functionality is simply not included. You'd need a userbot for that. You may be interested in [`ptbcontrib/username_to_chat_api`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/ptbcontrib/tree/main/ptbcontrib/username_to_chat_api).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.